# Run Command for System Date and Time in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I used to be able to run 'timedate.cpl' to bring up the calendar in Windows XP.  Is there an equivalent command in Windows 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not available in Windows 7 anymore.

You can try copying wincal from Windows Vista or from [here](http://www.vistax64.com/general-discussion/256132-i-am-looking-wincal-exe-my-win-7-a.html) then create a user variable with the name, for example wincal and point it to the executable file on your hard drive.

Comment: This answer is outdated. It works on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

timedate.cpl works for me in Windows 8 and I am sure it worked in Windows 7 as well.

```
%systemroot%\system32\control.exe timedate.cpl,Date and Time
```

is the full command. What does it do for you?

Comment: 'timedate.cpl' can be used but it brings up a big clock instead of the calendar that pops up when you click on the time on the bottom right hand corner of your monitor

Comment: @LloydBanks - Good information to have, update your question, to include what you want displayed exactly.

Comment: The calendar/clock popup when you hover over the time seems to be part of Windows explorer, not a control panel applet. I don't know how to get to that from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an equivalent command in Windows 7?

Yes:

```
timedate.cpl
```